# How to surround fixme notes with brackets?

Tags: fixme

I am using the [fixme](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixme) package for inserting notes in my LaTeX documents. The note text is by default bold, and I've enabled colors using `\fxsetup{theme=color}`. However, I would like to have even more separation from the surrounding text, especially on a black&white printouts.

Does the package *itself* support surrounding the text with (for example) square brackets.

I've checked the [fixme manual](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fixme/fixme.pdf), but I am getting lost in non-familiar terminology such as 'targets' and 'faces'.

For example, in the following example I would like the resulting PDF text 'FiXme Note: Something's wrong here' to be displayed in the PDF as either '[Fixme Note: Something's wrong here]' or 'Fixme Note: [Something's wrong here]' (both are fine with me).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomargin,inline,marginclue,draft]{fixme}
\begin{document}
   An apple is a pear \fxnote{Something's wrong here}
\end{document
```

Comment: Would you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @egreg: done as you asked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomargin,inline,marginclue,draft]{fixme}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  {\@fxuseface{inline}\ignorespaces[#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   An apple is a pear \fxnote{Something's wrong here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Only thing is that when using multiuser mode (e.g. by inserting `\fxsetup{theme=color, mode=multiuser}
\FXRegisterAuthor{me}{ame}{\color{red}Me}` and calling it via `\menote{This is a colored, user specific note}` the first bracket is not colored. But this is just a micro issue for me, or not an issue at all, actually.